# Catch FileNotFoundError and continue reading files

Tags: python, pathlib

I am performing file operations using `pathlib`, more or less like this:

```
for path in Path.cwd().glob("*.ipynb"):
    print(path)
```

The problem is that these files are on an external drive that tends to disconnect randomly. As a result the glob iterator throws a `FileNotFoundError`. This is a mockup of what is happening:

```
def hdd_disconnection_mockup():
    for i in range(3):
        if i == 1:
            raise FileNotFoundError
        yield f"Untitled{i}.ipynb"
```

```
>>> for path in hdd_disconnection_mockup():
        print(path)
Untitled0.ipynb
FileNotFoundError:
```

I would like to catch this exception and continue the execution of the for loop.

So far I have tried the following:

```
def catch_filenotfounderror(glob):
    try:
        yield next(glob)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

No exception is thrown, but this does not prevent the glob iterator to break the for loop.

```
>>> for path in catch_filenotfounderror(hdd_disconnection_mockup()):
        print(path)
Untitled0.ipynb
```

The expected output is

```
Untitled0.ipynb
Untitled2.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michael Dorner points out:

> When a generator throws an exception, it exits and you cannot continue consuming items it generates

So it's impossible to handle exceptions outside of a generator.

### Solution

In the end I solved this pragmatically by converting the glob iterator to a tuple. This way, if there is a problem reading a path it happens at the beginning, before entering the for loop. Then, I handle the exception inside the for loop.

```
ipynb_paths = Path.cwd().glob("*.ipynb")
for path in tuple(ipynb_paths):
    try:
        # read from path ...
    except FileNotFoundError:
        continue
```

### Failed approach

For the record, I tried to create a "safety copy" of the iterator before `FileNotFoundError` is thrown. The idea was that if the exception happens I can send the computer to sleep a bit, hope that the HDD reconnects, then retry with the safety copy.

```
def catch_filenotfounderror(glob):
    while True:
        glob, safety_glob = tee(glob, 2)
        try:
            yield next(glob)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            sleep(0.1)  # Give some time to the HDD to reconnect
            glob = safety_glob
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Unfortunately the safety generator seems to be linked to its original, as it raises a `StopIteration` exception at the same point where the `FileNotFoundError` happens.

Here it is an example to demonstrate this behaviour.

```
class Gen:
    exception_thrown = False
    @classmethod
    def go(cls):
        yield "one"
        if not cls.exception_thrown:
            cls.exception_thrown = True
            raise Exception
        yield "two"

g1, g2 = tee(Gen.go(), 2)
```

```
>>> while True:
        print(next(g1))
'one'
Exception:
```

```
>>> while True:
        print(next(g2))
'one'
StopIteration:
```

The following is the behaviour I was expecting, assuming copies made with `tee` were completely disconnected:

```
>>> for i in Gen.go():
        print(i)
'one'
Exception:
>>> for i in Gen.go():
        print(i)
'one'
'two'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this not possible: When a generator throws an exception, it exits and you cannot continue consuming items it generates.

Since you don't handle the exception anyway, you probably can check the file right before reading to avoid `FileNotFoundError`:

```
from pathlib import Path

my_file = Path('/path/to/file')
if my_file.exists():
    # read file
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that even if .exists() returns True there is no guarantee that the file is going to be found as the HDD can disconnect at any time.

Comment: That's true. But depending on your use case, you might then monitor the directory (e.g., via https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) instead of silently ignoring `FileNotFoundError `?